# How can we implement Facebook app like "pull to reload" option?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

How can we implement FACEBOOK APP like "pull to reload" option for loading more data in tableView .(FACEBOOK use this option in Wall Posts ). If you have ever used facebook app u already notice that way of loading more data.

Can any one help me to solve this puzzle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be fair, it's a Tweetie/Twitter for iOS feature. Credit where it's due. :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the whole three20 library, you can just use the EGORefreshTable Header View, which does exactly what you ask.

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 0):

Facebook app use [three20 library](http://three20.info/) which handle the more button that you ask.

Try this library. It's very good and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such behavior by implementing `scrollViewDidScroll:` method of scroll view delegate. Check contentOffset.y property & if its value is less than, for instance, -30, start update.

```
tableWithInfo.delegate = myContoller;

...

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    if (aScrollView.contentOffset.y < -30) { [self startUpdate]; }
}
```